# Sql how to have multiple entries in one column

Tags: mysql

I am creating a sql table users there are three columns id,username, favourite colours.user favourite colours maybe more than one like red,blue.how to store these values in favourite colours column.i am using mysql.

Comment: Two possible choices :
1. consider storing the favorite_color in a separate table, linking to the user table by a key
2. store the favorite colors in a single data field -- colors separated by commas
(For sure 1 is better from a db design perspective.)

Comment: @KenLee 2 is not an option at all. Or, like, shooting yourself in a foot is an "option" from this perspective

Comment: @KenLee: never store comma separated values. If you really **have to** de-normalize a model (assuming there are valid reasons to to do so) choose at least a "structured" type like JSON. But indeed: in this case a properly normalized model with a one-to-many relationship is the better solution

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That really depends whether this is a homework exercise or a practical one. The OP tagged this question 'php', and php has facilities for manipulating JSON, as I point out in my answer below.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: JSON is an acceptable solution to de-normalization. Storing comma separated values never is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's true. My point was that denormalization might be acceptable in this instance, unless normalization is the *point* of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The by-Codd correct approach would be to split off favourite colour into a separate table. The columns would be `id` and `colour`, the primary key would be both columns combined, and `id` would be a foreign key referencing `users.id`. It might also be useful to put a non-unique index on `favourites.id` for performance, but that would be an optimization exercise.

The other option would be to make `favourite_colour` a JSON column and store the colours as a JSON array; for a small exercise like this that might be simpler, as you could use PHP's JSON facilities to manipulate it.